# use g() or not in 'sommer' package

Tags: r

There are two prediction examples of GCA and SCA model based on wheat dataset and corn dataset in 'sommer' package. In these two cases, one used g() and the other not. I'm a little confused about this. 'random=' in mmer2 has indicated the random effect, why use g()  to indicate random effect again? Actually,  I found evaluation on GCA and SCA variation are different whether using g(). How do I understand the difference?  I'm not sure if use the g() in my prediction work.

Answer (score 0):

In sommer version <= 3.6 the g() function is used to specify the presence of a known variance covariance matrix for the levels of the random effect. For example:

```
random=~g(x), ginverse=list(x=A)
```

would be used to provide the relationship matrix A that specify the relationship among the levels of the random effect x. In sommer >= 3.7 this is specified in the Gu argument of the vs() function. For example the same would be specified as:

```
random=~vs(x, Gu=A)
```